# ¿Por qué aparece el error unhandledRejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

Estoy implementando un login con las siguientes especificaciones en el código, pero me da el error anteriormente mencionado.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando

```
  app.post('/auth', async(req, res) => {
    const user = req.body.user;
    const pass = req.body.pass;
    let passwordHash = await bcryptjs.hash(pass, 8);
    if (user && pass) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE = ?', [user], async(error, results) => {
            if (results.length == 0 || !(await bcryptjs.compare(pass, results[0].pass))) {
                res.send('USUARIO Y/O PASSWORD INCORRECTO');
            } else {
                res.send('LOGIN CORRECTO');
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Te falta colocar en tu where el username o el nombre del campo(ya depende de como lo tengas en tu tabla) de donde estés validando tu consulta `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?`

Comment: Mil gracias @JaimeJonathanOrtizVelazco, la respuesta fue efectiva

Comment: @AlejoConsuegra recuerda marcarle la respuesta como aceptada! Imagino que está claro que no estabas controlando el caso en el que falle la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el código corregido, denotando que el problema era la falta de el `username` o el campo de la tabla con el que querías comparar tu nombre de usuario a consultar a un lado del `where`.

```
app.post('/auth', async(req, res) => {
    const user = req.body.user;
    const pass = req.body.pass;
    let passwordHash = await bcryptjs.hash(pass, 8);
    if (user && pass) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?', [user], async(error, results) => {
            if (results.length == 0 || !(await bcryptjs.compare(pass, results[0].pass))) {
                res.send('USUARIO Y/O PASSWORD INCORRECTO');
            } else {
                res.send('LOGIN CORRECTO');
            }
        })
    }
})
```